# English in Math, x y's

Tags: mathematics

Suppose there are two variables, x and y. Now, I want to describe that "there are many y's, and the number of y is x." For example, a number=yy...y and its length is x. Is "there are x y's in this number" grammarly correct and readable for native speakers? Is "there are x y in it" correct?

Comment: Wrong group for the question, I think. Wouldn't a correct mathematical expression be the same across multiple languages?

Comment: Don't try to write complex mathematical ideas in English.  Use mathematical notation.  (for example S = {y,y,y,y,y}  then |S| = 1, since there is only one element in S.

Comment: Are you talking about the decimal representation of a number, like “One seventh, or 0.142857… repeating, has in its thousandths place the **digit** 2”?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sentence is not clearly understandable. If *x* is a known number you could write something like "There are seven *y*'s in S". Two consecutive mathematical symbols are often difficult to understand, so I prefer writing the number as a word. The apostrophe is often used with the plural "s" in this situation.

If you need to use the numeral for *x*, or if *x* is unknown, it would be clearer to use something like "There are *x* values of *y* in the set *S*".

Comment: I'd prefer "copies" or "instances" of y. But since the relationship between the different y's hasn't been clearly explained here, I have my doubts about it being understood by its intended audience.